# laravel angular add post 500 error

Tags: php, angular, laravel

I'm trying to submit a post using angular, I was following this [tutorial](https://www.codetutorial.io/laravel-5-angularjs-tutorial/) and I get the following error.

> $http.post(...).success is not a function Failed to load resource: the
>   server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> $http.post(...).success is not a function
>       at b.$scope.addPost (main.js:18)

Here is the route:

`Route::post('auth/post', 'PostController@storePost')->name('add.post');`

PostController

```
public function storePost(Request $request)
{
    $data = request()->validate([
     'title' => 'required|max:120',
     'body' => 'required|max:1000'
    ]);

    $data['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;

    $post = Post::create($data);


    // return redirect('/home')->withMessage('A new post was created.');

    return Response::json(array('success' => true));
}
```

Main.js

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.posts = {};

    $scope.addPost = function(){
        $http.post('/auth/post', {
            title: $scope.mytitle,
            body: $scope.mybody

        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            $scope.posts.push(data);
            $scope.post = '';


        });

    };
}]);
```

Comment: check your logs, what do they show?

Comment: @Fred-ii- `$http.post(...).success is not a function
    at b.$scope.addPost (main.js:18)`

Comment: Google that error you posted, quite a few hits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed success to then, and it worked.

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.posts = {};

    $scope.addPost = function(){
        $http.post('/auth/post', {
            title: $scope.mytitle,
            body: $scope.mybody

        }).then(function(data, status, headers, config){
            $scope.posts.push(data);
            $scope.post = '';


        });

    };
}]);
```